# Java Swing scrollable Frame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

How can I add a scroll bar to my frame using `Java Swing`? I have a lot of content in a panel and need to make it scrollable to not take the full screen height..

I've tried the folliwing code but it simply adds a scrollbar without having the posibility to scroll the content

```
// add the panel to a JScrollPane
JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
// only a configuration to the jScrollPane...
jScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
jScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

// Then, add the jScrollPane to your frame
frame.getContentPane().add(jScrollPane);
```

This is my code:

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 665);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblPersonalInfo = new JLabel("Personal Information");
    lblPersonalInfo.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
    lblPersonalInfo.setBounds(110, 11, 185, 14);
    panel.add(lblPersonalInfo);

    JLabel lblGender = new JLabel("Gender");
    lblGender.setBounds(10, 111, 46, 14);
    panel.add(lblGender);

    JLabel lblAddress = new JLabel("Address");
    lblAddress.setBounds(10, 164, 58, 14);
    panel.add(lblAddress);

    JLabel lblMobile = new JLabel("Mobile");
    lblMobile.setBounds(10, 189, 46, 14);
    panel.add(lblMobile);

    JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("E-mail");
    lblEmail.setBounds(10, 214, 46, 14);
    panel.add(lblEmail);

    JRadioButton rdbtnM_2 = new JRadioButton("M");
    rdbtnM_2.setBounds(74, 133, 109, 23);
    panel.add(rdbtnM_2);

    JRadioButton rdbtnF = new JRadioButton("F");
    rdbtnF.setBounds(74, 107, 109, 23);
    panel.add(rdbtnF);

    JTextPane textName = new JTextPane();
    textName.setBounds(95, 36, 302, 20);
    panel.add(textName);

    JTextPane textNationality = new JTextPane();
    textNationality.setBounds(95, 61, 302, 20);
    panel.add(textNationality);

    JTextPane textDate = new JTextPane();
    textDate.setBounds(95, 86, 302, 20);
    panel.add(textDate);

    JTextPane textAddress = new JTextPane();
    textAddress.setBounds(95, 164, 302, 20);
    panel.add(textAddress);

    JLabel lblWebsiteblog = new JLabel("Website/Blog");
    lblWebsiteblog.setBounds(10, 244, 78, 23);
    panel.add(lblWebsiteblog);

    JTextPane textWebsite = new JTextPane();
    textWebsite.setBounds(95, 239, 302, 20);
    panel.add(textWebsite);

    JLabel lblProfesional = new JLabel("Profesional Experience");
    lblProfesional.setBounds(10, 267, 133, 23);
    panel.add(lblProfesional);


    JLabel lblEducationAndTraining = new JLabel("Education and Training");
    lblEducationAndTraining.setBounds(10, 441, 133, 14);
    panel.add(lblEducationAndTraining);

    JTextArea textProfesional = new JTextArea();
    textProfesional.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textProfesional.setBounds(40, 301, 384, 129);
    panel.add(textProfesional);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textProfesional);
    scrollPane.setBounds(40, 301, 384, 129);
    panel.add(scrollPane);

    JTextArea textEducation = new JTextArea();
    textEducation.setBounds(40, 466, 384, 142);
    panel.add(textEducation);

    scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane(textEducation);
    scrollPane_1.setBounds(40, 466, 384, 142);
    panel.add(scrollPane_1);
}
```

Comment: This - `panel.setLayout(null);` is going to prevent the `JScrollPane` from calculating the size of the pane, which will prevent it from determining when the scrollbars should be shown

Answer (score 3):

```
panel.setLayout(null);
```

Don't use a null layout.

The scrollbars will only appear when the preferred size of the panel is greater than the size of the scroll pane. When you use a null layout the preferred size is (0, 0) so there is no reason to show scrollbars.

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. When you use layout managers, the preferred size of the panel will be calculated by the layout manager.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Alternatively, he can just set the preferred size directly `panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(465, 624));` and keep the null layout, but I agree that it must be discouraged. Also I recommend MigLayout http://www.miglayout.com/

Comment: @YagoMéndezVidal, no, you don't want to set the preferred size manually!!! It will just be a random number that should change when you add/remove components. Let the layout manager calculate the value, that is one of the jobs of the layout manager.

Comment: That number is as random as all the other `setBounds` in the code, that's why I tell it must be discouraged and I recommended one given layout for his case.

Comment: @YagoMéndezVidal, `That number is as random as all the other setBounds in the code,` Exactly, which is why my answer was to NOT use a null layout (and therefore setBounds). You comments add nothing to the answer and are opposite to what I was suggesting. Please delete them.